# Some PHP process should be done while Jquery toggle button is clicked without redirecting the page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

i have a toggle button on Jquery which has to show some extra info. it works good and i wanna to do some process on PHP in order to do in back end without redirecting the toggle page (which shows some extra info). i am breaking my head too long . kindly help me out please... here is my Jquery code

```
<div class="hidetext"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".hidetext").click(function () {
            $(".text").toggle("slow",function(){
            });
        });
    });

    $('#hidetext').change(function() {
        this.form.submit();
    });
</script>
<form action="http://localhost/test/test/index.php" method="post" id="doSite">
    <input type="hidden" name="credits" value="<?php echo $email;?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="credits" value="<?php echo 2;?>">
    <button class="hidetext">Click More Info</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Ajax is your friend here. Take a look at the [jQuery ajax function](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Comment: You are using '#hidetext' , which is not exists.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ajax for this.

```
        $.ajax({
        dataType: "json",
        data: {"x": $x},
        url:   'php/x.php',
        type:  'post',
        beforeSend: function(){
            //What is done before to send
            },
        success: function(respuesta){
            //what is done after send
            $("x").html(respuesta.html);
        },
        error:    function(xhr,err){ 
            alert("readyState: "+xhr.readyState+"\nstatus: "+xhr.status+"\n \n responseText: "+xhr.responseText);
        }
    });
```